# Protein conservation analysis with trident scores in R script

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I am currently working on analyzing protein conservation across amino acid positions using Trident scores as output from the `MstatX` tool. I have 40,000 Trident score files, each containing amino acid positions and their respective scores.

To streamline my analysis, I initially wrote a bash script to loop through each file and then implemented an R script for the calculations. The R script calculates moving averages with different spans to identify regions with high deviation in local protein conservation, referred to as "hotspots." These hotspots are then analyzed to determine the strongest deviation, its position, and related metrics.

Here is a snippet of my R script:

```r
# assign input files to a vector 
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

# put sample name in variable
sample <- sprintf("%s", args[1])

# load sample and make data frame
raw.entropy <- read.table(sprintf("%s", args[1]))
col.names <- c("AA.pos", "Entropy.Score")
colnames(raw.entropy) <- col.names
AA.pos <- raw.entropy$AA.pos
Entropy.Score <- raw.entropy$Entropy.Score

# make sample name nicer
sub("_entropyscores", "", sample) -> sample

# load ggplot
library(ggplot2)

# calculate short and long moving averages
mydata <- ggplot(data=raw.entropy, aes(x=AA.pos)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Entropy.Score), size=2, color="black") +
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(y=Entropy.Score), method = "loess", 
                          color = "red", span = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(mapping=aes(y=Entropy.Score), method = "loess", 
                          color = "blue", span = 0.4) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) +
  labs(title = sprintf("%s", args[1]), x = "Amino Acid Positions", 
       y = "Trident Score")

# infer ratios between short and long span moving averages
# ratios represent extent to which local conservation is adhered to
# ratio around 1 means perfect conservation, ratio around 0 
# means poor conservation 

rolling_mean_10 <- layer_data(mydata, 2)$y
rolling_mean_50 <- layer_data(mydata, 3)$y
ratios <- rolling_mean_10/rolling_mean_50

# find index value of 10th percentile
lowerbound <- NULL
for (i in (0.1*length(rolling_mean_10)):length(rolling_mean_10)) { 
  if (rolling_mean_10[i] >= 0.9*median(raw.entropy$Entropy.Score)){
    lowerbound<-i
break
}
}

# find index value of 90th percentile
upperbound <- NULL
for (i in (0.9*length(rolling_mean_10)):1) { 
  if (rolling_mean_10[i] >= 0.9*median(raw.entropy$Entropy.Score)){ 
    upperbound <- i
break
}
}

# find location in sequence with highest deviation in 
# local protein conservation
which(ratios==min(ratios[lowerbound:upperbound])) -> hotspot
ratios[hotspot] -> cutoff
layer_data(mydata, 3)$x[hotspot] -> x
percentile <- x/length(raw.entropy$AA.pos)*100

# write relevant items to standard output
# order is cluster name, strongest deviation, rounded amino acid 
# position, percentile where deviation occurred
cat(sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", sample, cutoff, round(x),   
    round(percentile, 2)), file="./output_deviation.txt", append=TRUE)
```

After writing the output file, I aim to create a density plot with the x-axis representing the strongest deviation of each input file. However, the current method does not capture the expected bimodal distribution. I am seeking advice on alternative ways to calculate small but strong deviations beyond using simple moving averages.

Some options I've explored include EMA, z-scores, step detection, and anomaly detection. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Comment: This questions is not really about programming, but about methods development. It is therefore better suited to other sites, such as the Statistics, Bioinformatics, or Data Science stack exchanges.